# Objective-C block to Swift Closure translating Estimote "Examples" app

Tags: swift, closures, block

I'm translating the Estimote "Examples" iOS app from Objective-C to Swift and have run into a problem translating the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)     void (^completion)(CLBeacon *);

- (id)initWithScanType:(ESTScanType)scanType completion:(void (^)(id))completion
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.scanType = scanType;
        self.completion = [completion copy];
    }
    return self;
}

demoViewController = [[ESTBeaconTableVC alloc] initWithScanType:ESTScanTypeBeacon
                                                 completion:^(CLBeacon *beacon) {

  ESTDistanceDemoVC *distanceDemoVC = [[ESTDistanceDemoVC alloc] initWithBeacon:beacon];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:distanceDemoVC animated:YES];
}];
```

How can this be translated to Swift?  I've tried many solutions from other posts and documentation, but still haven't gotten the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, initializers are called `init`; they do not have `func`. And to call the superclass initializer, you do `super.init()`, without needing to check the return for `nil`. Also, the class's own properties should be initialized before calling the superclass initializer:

```
init(scanType: ESTScanType completion: (CLBeacon? -> Void)?) {
    self.scanType = scanType
    self.completion = completion
    super.init()
}
```

Then, you create an object and call an initializer by calling the name of the class. You can use a trailing closure expression if the last argument of a call is a function type. And you should use optional chaining instead of forcing an optional, to preserve the same behavior as Objective-C where it doesn't crash when called on `nil`.

```
demoViewController = ESTBeaconTableVC(scanType:ESTScanTypeBeacon) { beacon in
  let distanceDemoVC = ESTDistanceDemoVC(beacon:beacon)
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(distanceDemoVC animated:true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After much trial and error (not the way I like to code), this code seems to work:

```
var completion: ((value: CLBeacon?) -> Void)?

func initWithScanType(scanType: ESTScanType,
                    completion: ((AnyObject?) -> Void)) -> UIViewController
{
    if let _:ESTBeaconTableVC = ESTBeaconTableVC()
    {
        self.scanType = scanType
        self.completion = completion
    }
    return self
}

demoViewController = ESTBeaconTableVC().initWithScanType(
                        ESTBeaconTableVC.ESTScanType.ESTScanTypeBeacon,
                                                           completion:{ beacon in

    let distanceDemoVC = ESTDistanceDemoVC().initWithBeacon(beacon as! CLBeacon)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(distanceDemoVC!, animated:true)
})
```

I have not found a good reference that explains the transition from Obj-C to Swift for the variable declaration, function definition and function call all in one place, using one coherent example.